# Get table row with value

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table containing default and override values that, when simplified, looks like so:

```
create table t (
    identifier varchar(20),
    override varchar(20),
    data1 int,
    data2 varchar(2),
    ...
)
```

I want to get all items out of the table that have a blank in the `override` column. **Unless** there is a row with the same `identifier` and a non blank `override`. In that case I want the `override` to be returned **instead**.

I suspect I want to do something with `GROUP BY` to select the row but I can't figure out how to ensure I'm getting the right values in the `datax` columns.

Comment: It's possible there may be a case where there is a row with an `override` value, without a corresponding blank override row. In this case, I still want the override row returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would achieve the solution ... perform a sub query on and get `sameIdentifierWithOverride` - this is the number of rows in the table with the same identifier but with an override that isn't empty. You can then use `having` to filter down the results ..

```
select  *, 
        (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.identifier=t.identifier and t2.override != '') sameIdentifierWithOverride 
from t where override='' having sameIdentifierWithOverride=0
```